# Cómo agregar multiples objetos en un array con select multiple?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, select

quizás es muyyy fácil pero estoy arrancando. Tengo el siguiente código que funcionaba bien, pero le agregué el multiple al v-select y se me complicó. Al agregar una marca y VARIOS modelos sólo crea un sólo objeto, y necesito que me agrege un objeto abajo de otro. Ejemplo, si elijo la marca Ford y los modelos Focus, Ka y Mondeo, quiero que el listado muestre:

objetc: Marca: Ford Modelo: Focus

object: Marca: Ford Modelo: Ka

object: Marca: Ford Modelo: Mondeo

Muchas gracias de antemano!

```
 <v-select  
v-model="marca" 
:on-search="selectMarca" 
label="marca"
:options="arrayMarca"
placeholder="Buscar Marca...">
</v-select>

<v-select multiple 
v-model="modelo" 
:on-search="selectModelo" 
label="model"
:options="arrayModelo"
placeholder="Buscar Modelo...">
</v-select>

<button @click="agregarDetalle()">

<tbody v-if="arrayDetalle.length">
    <tr v-for="(detalle,index) in arrayDetalle" :key="detalle.id">
        <td class="align-middle"  v-text="detalle.marca"></td>
        <td class="align-middle"  v-text="detalle.modelo"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
-------------------------------------------------------
<script>
    import vSelect from 'vue-select';
    export default {
        data (){
            return {
                marca:'',
                modelo:[],
            }
        },
        components:{
            vSelect
        },
        methods : {
            agregarDetalle(){
                let me=this;
                me.arrayDetalle.push({
                    marca: me.marca,
                    modelo: me.modelo,
                });
            },
        },
</script>
```

Comment: Este codigo no tirar error? hay cosas que estan en tu render, que no estan definidas en tu data. Por ejemplo, arrayDetalle de donde sale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dejando de lado que en el código faltan ciertas cosas, que me imagino que las has omitido al preguntar. Este código hará que tengas un objeto por cada combinación de marca/modelo seleccionada.

```
agregarDetalle(){
    let me=this;

    me.modelo.forEach(el => {

        me.arrayDetalle.push({
            marca: me.marca,
            modelo: el.nombre,
        });

    });

},
```

Comment: Gracias Francisco, entendiste todo! Omití varias cosas sólo para preguntar. Ahora, me aparece el objeto modelo y dentro el id con el nombre del modelo. Cómo puedo hacer para sólo mostrar el nombre?

Comment: No entiendo del todo que quieres decir, puedes poner el output de como se ve?

Comment: En la tabla me imprime el listado perfecto de esta manera: • Marca: Ford Modelo: {"id":1, "nombre":"Mondeo"} • Marca: Ford Modelo: {"id":2, "nombre":"Ka"}

Comment: Ya veo, he modificado la respuesta para que funcione como pides

Comment: Sos un crack, gracias por tu ayuda!